# onBlur for div with input

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 `input` within a `div` and I want to do something when the user remove the focus away from the `card1`. The blur event listener that I attached to `card1` is not working, how can I do this on a `div`?

```js
$('.card').blur( (event) => {
  console.log("blur")
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card1">
  <input class="title1">
  <input class="content1">
</div>

<div class="card2">
  <input class="title2">
  <input class="content2">
</div>
```

Comment: where is "card" class

Comment: edit: revised to `card1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("input").blur(function () {
                        alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
                    });
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
            <input class="title">
            <input class="content">
        </div>
```

Comment: that would trigger the alert as I move from one input to another within the same div. I want to trigger the alert when the user moves away from both the input

Answer (score 0):

Add `tabindex="0"` to the `.card` div, that allows you to focus the div.

```js
$('.card').blur( (event) => {
  console.log("blur")
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card" tabindex="0">
  <input class="title">
  <input class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: I revised the code in my question. I want the alert to trigger when I move from `card1` to `card2`.

Answer (score 0):

it is fine:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var flag=0;
$('.card1').hover( function() {
flag=1
});
$('.card2').hover( function() {
if(flag==1)
{
console.log("ok");
 flag=0;
 } 
});
});

<div class="card1">
  <input class="title1">
  <input class="content1">
</div>
<div class="card2">
      <input class="title2">
      <input class="content2">
</div>
```

Comment: its not hover its focus

Comment: @awesomeguy read this-> I revised the code in my question. I want the alert to trigger when I move from card1 to card2. – jj008

Answer (score 0):

After some research I figured you can use `document.activeElement` to determine which input is focused

```js
var checked = false;
var currentElement;
var prevElement;
$("input").focus(function() {
  if(checked) {
    checked = false;
    return;
  } else {
    prevElement = currentElement;
    currentElement = document.activeElement.id;
    if((prevElement === "title1" || prevElement === "content1") && (currentElement === "title2" || currentElement === "content2")) {
      alert("focus moved from card1 to card2");
    }else if((prevElement === "title2" || prevElement === "content2") && (currentElement === "title1" || currentElement === "content1")) {
      alert("focus moved from card2 to card1");
    }
    checked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card1">
  Card1
  <input id="title1">
  <input id="content1">
</div>

<div class="card2">
  Card2
  <input id="title2">
  <input id="content2">
</div>
```

The first part working with the `checked` variable is to make sure that the function doesn't run over and over again.

The second part sets the current selected element and previously selected element to check if focus has moved from a div.

Also it is a good practice to use `id` instead of `class` for elements like these because `id` is unique but `class` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check focus on the input elements inside each parent and add some 'active' class to the parent. If you switch from one card to another you need to check if siblings are having active class.

```js
$('.card1,.card2').find('input').focus( (event) => {
 if (!$(event.target).parent().hasClass('active')){
    alert("focus on " + $(event.target).closest('div').attr('class'))
    $(event.target).closest('div').addClass('active'); 
  } else {
    if ($(event.target).closest('div').siblings().hasClass('active')) {
      $(event.target).closest('div').siblings().removeClass('active')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <div class="card1">
    <input class="title">
    <input class="content">
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="card2">
    <input class="title">
    <input class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```